# Haskell mix two lists

Tags: haskell

Im about to write my first haskell program, so I need your help. I want to interlink two lists. For example;

```
a = [4,8,20]
b = [3,5,17,56,89,30]

interlink a b = [4,3,8,5,20,17,56,89,30]
```

The resulting list must cointain the elements of List a and b alternately. If one List is longer then the elements of the longer list should be added to the result list after the shorter list mashed up with the elements of the longer list. I think you saw that in my example above.

Now how do i do this in Haskell??

My start

```
mix :: [a]->[a]->[a]
mix (x:l1) (y:l2) = (x:y:[])
mix [] [] = []
```

Please, can you help me??

Comment: You're on the right track. What happens when one of the lists is empty, but the other is not?

Comment: And what do you do with `l1` and `l2`?

Comment: Thanks I solved it with a bit of trying :)

Answer (score 2):

I do not have an interpreter available to use as I am on a different computer to usual, but here is some code:

```
mix :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
mix (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : mix xs ys
mix x [] = x
mix [] y = y
```

Edit: I just tested this online, I believe it works.

Comment: Thanks alex got the same after some trying. Works like a charm :)

Comment: Please vote for my answer if it is the solution to your question!

Comment: You might also like to match only on the first argument: `mix (x:xs) ys = x:mix ys xs; mix [] ys = ys`. It's a cute trick I've [used a few times](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41192723/791604) myself.

Answer (score 1):

So there are two functions `transpose` and `concat`.

```
-- transpose :: [[a]] -> [[a]] 
-- concat :: Foldable t => t [a] -> [a]
```

Since List already has an instance of Foldable this ends up being one line of code like so:

```
concat . transpose $ a : b : []
```

or

```
concat . transpose  $ [a,b]
```

The first step is to create a list of lists with transpose like so

```
λ> transpose  $ [a, b]
[[4,3],[8,5],[20,17],[56],[89],[30]]
```

which we then collapse into one.

The secret here is to use function composition. The `.` is a function that takes two functions and calls one after the other creating a larger function so:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

means: take the result of the first function, `transpose`, and feed it to the next one, `concat`.

We can chain as many functions as we wish as long as the types allow it. 
In our case the composition creates a function `[a] -> [a] -> [a]`